# User-friendly diff-capable windows-based backup software

Tags: windows, backup

There're the requirements/expectations:

- ability to both backup **to** an external drive and update local copy **from** an external HDD
- ability to produce non-compressed backup copy (the intention is to backup lots of images, those do not compress well anyway and it's time-consuming)
- ability to detect differences and backup/update only changed/added/removed files, not the whole archive
- ability to sync the folder structure as well
- capability to pre-setup desired backups so as to simplify the process of backing up the data (basically, ability to start the backup / local update in one click)
- user-friendliness. At least, after an initial configuration. End-user is not a computer-savvy person and not English-proficient either. So the software would preferably have icons and be generally easy to use
- windows-based
- (optional but preferred) free software

Essentially, there're 2 PCs with the same library of images and (separately) some documents. The intention is to keep a backup copy on a couple of external HDDs and, as changes may come from both PCs, use the HDDs to synchronise the library and documents among the PCs, while using the HDDs as a main backup.

So far I've tried several kinds of backup software and none was it. FBackup, for instance, failed to sync the same library from 2 PCs. Some other wouldn't produce non-compressed backup copies, another one could only backup the whole archive, not the changed files or could only backup files, but not the folder structure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Phew, I never synchronized 2 PCs that way, but I can only recommend [bvckup2](https://bvckup2.com/). You could check whether that to- and from-synchronization is fine for you during the trial period. It's really a fine tool. I purchased 5 licenses although I needed only 1, just to support the vendor.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, thanks, I'll definitely give it a go. The words "It's not a two-way sync" are a bit alarming though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the same kind of software - ended up using Allway Sync.

Pros

- Works for syncing both from and to external drive.
- Detects differences and added/updated/deleted files.
- Supports folders
- windows based
- free version is enough for my needs

Cons

- Wouldn't call it very user-friendly or one-time-settupable

All in all it works and does exactly what we needed to be done.